# ERROR: Failed to parse POMs java.io.IOException: Cannot run program " /lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.302.b08-0.amzn2.0.1.x86_64/bin/java"

Tags: maven, jenkins

[image]

[image]

when i Biuld Now manually in jenkins for the maven project and on Source code management i choose Git Repositories (Repository URL https://github.com/sathish-sundar/java-project-NM.git). I am getting below error as image attached. Someone could help me here please i am new to the Devops world.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

```
I was able to figure it out by adding the value in 
Dasboard - Manage jenkins -configure system- global properties
under list of variables
Name : JAVA_HOME
Value : /lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.302.b08-0.amzn2.0.1.x86_64/jre

and adding the JAVA_HOME in 
Dasboard- manage jenkins- global tool configuration- JDK -
JDK installation- Add JDK 
Under JDK
Name : JAVA_HOME
Value : /lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.302.b08-0.amzn2.0.1.x86_64/jre

and i had recevied the console output as per requirement.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).